# in Sql Server query how do I express bigint = 28648853947604 as gigabytes in a select

Tags: sql

```
Select TotalOriginalFileSize 'not sure" as SizeGB
from mytable

TotalOriginalFileSize(bigint, not null)
```

value 28648853947604

Answer (score 2):

Just do some basic math like:

```
SELECT (28648853947604 /1024/1024/1024) --(26681.3244182653722753)
```

- dividing with first 1024 gives you KB
- dividing the KB with 1024 gives you MB
- dividing MB with 1024 gives you GB.

So your query would be:

```
SELECT (TotalOriginalFileSize  /1024/1024/1024) as SizeGB
FROM MyTable
```

For getting results back until two decimal places use:

```
SELECT CAST((28648853947604 /1024/1024/1024) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: Thanks That put me on the right track. Also if its TeraBytes I guess I would add /1024 then?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean gigabyte as 10^9 bytes:

```
Select TotalOriginalFileSize / 1000000000 as SizeGB
from mytable
```

If you mean gigabytes as in 2^30 bytes (SI unit GiB):

```
Select TotalOriginalFileSize / 1073741824 as SizeGiB
from mytable
```

If you need fractional values, add `.0` to the static divisor values.  If you need to be sure about accuracy with fractional numbers, cast the numerator and divisor to `NUMERIC()` or `DECIMAL()` with appropriate scales and precision.  If you need to round the results, use the `ROUND()` function, making sure the precision you defined is sufficient for your rounding to be accurate.